# C++: Splitting a string with multiple delimiters and keep the delimiters in the results?

Tags: c++, c, string, stl

Is there a good way to split a string (in C or C++) by multiple delimiters while keeping the delimiters as part of the split strings? The only way I've found to do this is using regex and I'd rather not have to pull in another library just to do this? (I'm using STL for strings, not using Boost).

Comment: You want the delimiter to be in the term preceding it or the one following it? (e.g. CSV: `this,is,an,example` to become `this,` `is,` `an,` `example` OR `this` `,is` `,an` `,example`?)

Comment: Following, though it doesn't really matter, I just need to be able to assemble them back again.

Comment: You could achieve that with find_first_of() and substr(), but it wouldn't be one call...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without regexp, though I'm not sure if it's faster or slower:

```
vector<string> split(string& stringToSplit)
{
    vector<string> result;
    size_t pos = 0, lastPos = 0;
    while ((pos = stringToSplit.find_first_of(";,|", lastPos)) != string::npos)
    {
        result.push_back(stringToSplit.substr(lastPos, pos-lastPos+1));
        lastPos = pos+1;
    }
    result.push_back(stringToSplit.substr(lastPos));
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a lookahead to do that. Split with the expression:

```
(?=,)
```

For comma delimiters, and add in (perhaps in a character class: `[ ... ]`) the other delimiters you want to split.

So, `this,is,an,example` becomes: `this` `,is` `,an` `,example` (i.e. the delimiter goes with the term following it)

You'll use a lookbehind otherwise (meaning `(?<=,)`) to get: `this,` `is,` `an,` `example`.